# Fetching RSS Feeds with Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is there any documentation for fetching RSS feeds and writing it in database with Azure functions? I want to do it in Javascript but I could not find a good documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Azure Functions` written in JS are based in nodejs code. So in order to accomplish your scenario you could install node modules to do so, modules like:

- [feed-read](https://www.npmjs.com/package/feed-read), for reading rss
- Depending on your database you could use modules like:

  - [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)
  - [mysql-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)